# why i always get InsufficientAuthenticationException in spring sercurity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint class handle AuthenticationException

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String errMsg = "";

        if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(BadCredentialsException.class)) {
            errMsg = "Invalid username or password!";
        } 
        else {
            errMsg = "Unknown error - " + e.getMessage();
        }
        System.out.println(e.getClass().toString());
//      System.out.println(e + "this is e");
//      errMsg = e.toString();
        //request.setAttribute("message", errMsg);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("message", errMsg);
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.htm?error=true");
    }
}
```

My sercurity config

```
...
.and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                        //.accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.htm"),
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler())
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
```

My Provider

```
...
try {
            UserProfile userProfile = loginServiceDao.doLogin(userProfileDTO);
            if(null != userProfile) {
                List<CurrentUserRole> grantedAuthoritiesList = new ArrayList<CurrentUserRole>();
                CurrentUserRole cur = new CurrentUserRole();
                cur.setName("ROLE_USER");
                grantedAuthoritiesList.add(cur);

                CurrentUserProfile cup = new CurrentUserProfile();
                cup.setUsername(userName);
                cup.setFirstName("Nang");
                cup.setLastName("Nguyen Hien");
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(cup, password, grantedAuthoritiesList);
            }else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or password is not available.");
            }
        }catch(Throwable thr) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(thr);
        }
```

Why i always get InsufficientAuthenticationException when i enter wrong username and password?
I want to get BadCredentialsException instead.

Comment: Hi Nguyễn! Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same problem here. I hope that you solved it.